# Having trouble getting bound events to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have included the below code in the header of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery('#start_price').mouseleave(function() {
        alert('Hi!');
    });

</script>
```

I have tested it by putting my mouse into the text field with this ID and removing it, clicking outside of it but nothing fires. I checked the error console and there is nothing, so it looks like it's not even attempting to fire it.

http://jsfiddle.net/kRaJy/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't waiting for the element to exist in the dom.

Comment: @KevinB Ahh, good point - thanks! :)

Comment: Make sure you accept one of the other answers so that the question will appear as "Answered"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timing is everything when registering event handlers. You need to wait until document ready to do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#start_price').mouseleave(function() {
            alert('Hi!');
        });

});
```

Check out the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kRaJy/1/

Answer (score 3):

You have to execute your code on DOM ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code */ });
```

otherwise, `jQuery('#start_price')` won't match anyting, since the element has not been created yet.

Comment: @sp00m Except that can cause confusion because it doesn't really say what it does. Good point though

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseleave', '#start_price', function() {
    alert('Hi!');
});
```

If you bind the event to the document, and more precisely on the element, you won't need to wait for DOM to be ready.